# Python time integer issue

Tags: python, date, datetime, integer, timedelta

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between a 'then' and 'now'. I've altered the format so that I can compare it better (I dont need seconds or nanoseconds, etc)

the 'then' time comes from an ecryption, and it's being parsed through to compare, which is what gives the error I'm afraid.

```
def decrypt_and_compare_date():
        from Crypto.Cipher import XOR
        from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date
        import base64
        import config
        cipher = XOR.new(cryptopassword)
        encrypted = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(config.event_date))
        then = date(encrypted)
        now = date(2015,10,5)
        days = (now - then).days
        print days + " days ago."
```

gives me the following error:

> TypeError: an integer is required

if I use the * on this line:

```
    then = date(encrypted)
```

It then parses me this error.

> TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

date(encrypted) should be `2015,7,1`

Does anyone know the magic trick?

Comment: What is the value of `encrypted`?

Comment: `date("2015,7,1")` is different from `date(2015,7,1)`, use `date(*map(int, date_string.split(",")))` instead. You can't use `1 + " days ago"`, use `"%d days ago" % days`. Python is strongly typed. Learn the difference between an object and its string representation (open REPL, import your module and play with various objects in it: call `repr(obj)`, `str(obj)`, `print(obj)`, `type(obj)`, `isinstance(obj, str)`. `encrypted` is a bad name for the result of `decrypt()` call, use `date_string` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `datetime.strptime()` to parse the string as date.

Example -

```
>>> s = "2015,7,1"
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s,'%Y,%m,%d').date()
>>> d
datetime.date(2015, 7, 1)
```

This is based on assumption that the second number in the string is month and the third is the date, if its opposite, interchange `%m` and `%d` in `'%Y,%m,%d'` .

Comment: sadly d = datetime.strptime(encrypted, "%Y,%m,%d").date()

returns as 2015-07-01, not as 2015, 7, 1

Comment: What is the difference, its a date object.

Comment: Anyway you are just subtracting the dates and taking the days between them?

Comment: I am, but I was unable to find out how to do it any other way than I tried. Every documentation I can find includes secondes and nanosecondes, and I really would like a DD-MM-YYY comparison between 2 dates.

Comment: Your code (with my modification - `then = datetime.strptime(encrypted,'%Y,%m,%d').date()`) should work, are you facing any issues?

Comment: (changed the date now to reflect better what is what) but it now comes through as a formatting issue.

ValueError: time data '30-12-2015' does not match format '%d,%m,%Y'

Comment: for your current format try the string - `'%d-%m-%Y'` .

Comment: That works, but now the comparison between dates goes bork. It gives me the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' I'm assuming I need 2x int? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82942/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-kagetaze).